# java script closure for asynchronous ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops

I have data like below and javascript two loops and ajax to get data.
The two loops works correctly with i j values. But if i add ajax inside the inner loop the requests are not going in sequence. I need the data to be fetched in the sequence of loops. How can we achieve this?

```
var final = {};
final.reports = ['a','b','c']
final.clients = ['x','y']
final.reportDataJson = [];

for(var i=0;i<final.reports.length;i++){
        (function(i,reactthis){

            for(var j=0;j<final.clients.length;j++){
                (function(i,j,final){
                    console.log(i+" "+j+" "+final.clients[j])
                    // this shows correct i j values
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html) {
                            var reportResponse = {
                                reportname : final.reports[i],
                                clientname : final.clients[j],
                                reporthtml : html,
                                reportgraph : ''
                            }
                            final.reportDataJson.push(reportResponse)
                            //console.log(i,j)
                            if( i == final.reports.length-1 && j == final.clients.length-1){

                                console.log(final.reportDataJson);

                            }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                            if( i == final.reports.length-1 && j == final.clients.length-1){
                            }
                        }
                    })              

                })
            }


        })(i,final);
    }
```

Comment: `// this shows correct i j values` - I doubt it, the code in there wont run

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous, and there's no guarantee that the order they are executed will be the order they finish in - therefore `if( i == final.reports.length-1 && j == final.clients.length-1){` is no guarantee that all the data has been received for a start, and of course, the order will probably be wrong ... look at `$.when` for a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the fact that `$.ajax` returns a Promise - with `$.when` - which waits for a number of Promises and returns the resolved values in order!

```
var final = {};
final.reports = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
final.clients = ['x', 'y'];
final.reportDataJson = [];

$.when.apply($, [].concat.apply([], final.reports.map(function(report) {
    return final.clients.map(function(client) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false
        }).then(function(results) {
            var html = results[0];
            // results[0] is same as success: html argument
            // results[1] is textStatus
            // results[2] is jqXHR
            return {
                reportname: report,
                clientname: client,
                reporthtml: html,
                reportgraph: ''
            };
        });
    })
}))).then(function() {
    final.reportDataJson = [].slice.call(arguments);
    console.log(final.reportDataJson);
});
```

use $.when.apply, because $.when takes arguments 1..n as promises

use [].concat.apply to "flatten" the array of arrays returned by the nested .map's

This is a little easier with native Promise

```
Promise.all([].concat.apply([], final.reports.map(function(report) {
    // code unchanged from above ....
}))).then(function(results) {
    final.reportDataJson = results;
    console.log(final.reportDataJson);
});
```

Promise.all takes an array of promises, and it's `.then` callback receives a single argument, the array of results of those promises

And for the sake of ES2015+ goodness

```
Promise.all([].concat.apply([], final.reports.map(report => final.clients.map(client => $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false
}).then(([html, status, jqXHR]) => ({
    reportname: report,
    clientname: client,
    reporthtml: html,
    reportgraph: ''
})))))).then(results => console.log(final.reportDataJson = results));
```